# How to implement offline support to API with also saving favorite item list saved

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I am building a app using API, through which I fetched data that is blogs I displayed them in my app, added a favorite button to add a blog as favorite and displaying them in favorite screen using riverpod, but now I want to implement offline support to API using SQLite with also having favorite list. I am very confused that whether I should create separate database for blog and fav blog or add a `isFavorite` field to the model or anything else, also how to do it.

```
class FavoriteBlogsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Blog>> {
  FavoriteBlogsNotifier() : super([]);
  bool toggleBlogFavoriteStatus(Blog blog) {
    final isBlogFavorite = state.contains(blog);
    if (isBlogFavorite) {
      state = state.where((m) => m.id != blog.id).toList();
      return false;
    } else {
      state = [...state, blog];
      return true;
    }
  }
}

final favoriteBlogsNotifier =
    StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteBlogsNotifier, List<Blog>>(
  (ref) {
    return FavoriteBlogsNotifier();
  },
);
```

```
class FavoriteBlogsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Blog>> {
  FavoriteBlogsNotifier() : super([]);
  bool toggleBlogFavoriteStatus(Blog blog) {
    final isBlogFavorite = state.contains(blog);
    if (isBlogFavorite) {
      state = state.where((m) => m.id != blog.id).toList();
      return false;
    } else {
      state = [...state, blog];
      return true;
    }
  }
}

final favoriteBlogsNotifier =
    StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteBlogsNotifier, List<Blog>>(
  (ref) {
    return FavoriteBlogsNotifier();
  },
);
```